# Unable to retrieve new intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications, push-notification

I'd like to ask you for help as after trying to figure this issue out for a couple of hours still can't get it works. 
I have a notification manager which process incoming GCM messages and creates notifications, however an intent, that is passed to pending intent, always got old extras (intent recycle) within activity.

```
intent.putExtra("user_id", id);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Lets say that I will receive two notifications from two different users and intent starts the same activity which displays that user ID. After click on first notification, activity is launched as usually and intent's extras contains user ID of first user. However, if I will remain within this activity, and click on another push notification, an activity is recreated (onDestroy is called) but, intent's extras contains user id of first user, not the second one.

Here is my question. How can I retrieve new intent extras? I've already tried to implement onNewIntent callback method, but it never get called, also tried to change flags but unsuccessfully and what's kinda weird to me is, that even after onDestroy callback is called, intent extras in next instance of that activity have old data...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass unique Id in place of just 0 when fetching `Activity` from `PendingIntent`:

```
int iUniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, iUniqueId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you fire your notifications either with the same id or with a inappropriate intent flag. As it is mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), when creating the pending intent you can set its flag. If you don't like the previous pending intent to be updated or overridden, you should set its flag to FLAG_ONE_SHOT. It indicates that although you have more than one pending intents sticking around in the system, each can be executed only once!

Conclusion: Your code should be sth like this:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

In this code the "id" is unique per pending intent and "intent" is the actual intent for the target activity.

Cheers